# How to display content in horizontal?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm using Session with PHP. And I'm not getting display horizontally. How do I do that?

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_GET['nome']) && $_GET!=['nome']){
    $lista_tarefa = array();
    $lista_tarefa['nome'] = $_GET['nome'];
    }



    if(isset($_GET['descricao'])){
        $lista_tarefa['descricao'] = $_GET['descricao'];
    } else {
        $lista_tarefa['descricao'] = '';
    }
```

**PHP+HTML:**

```
<table>

      <?php foreach ($lista_tarefa as $tarefa) : ?>

           <tr>
               <td> <?php echo $tarefa; ?> </td>
            </tr>

       <?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
```

I GUESS...

```
    $a=0;
        while($a<=3){
        foreach ($lista_tarefas as $tarefa): 
        echo $tarefa[a];
        if($a<=3){
          ????
        }
        $a++;

    }
```

but does not work. Could you help me?

Comment: to show the data in one line simply do the `foreach` inside the row `tr`. This  page http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp have more information about how html tables works.

Comment: It worked, thank you! but now there is another problem, ha ha. I want to add 5 points and display them in hrozintal. OK. But I want to add 5 more then 5 more then 5 more ....

When I do that, it display all the horzintal. When I add a further 5 values, want the same come down to the line below. How do I do that?